# Issue with making a Class with an enum Conform to Codable Protocol

Tags: swift, enums, codable

I'm new to IOS development and I'm trying to create an app where the wheel spins and randomly stops at a point, to push the information into user defaults i need to decode the custom object. however, when i try to make the class 'Codable' it gives me the error does not conform to protocol.

If i remove the enum it works but i need the enum to set the colour for each individual choice, is there a way to make this Codable ?

`TTFortuneWheel` is the `Pod` i installed to assist with the spinning animation.

```
import UIKit

import TTFortuneWheel

class CarnivalWheel: FortuneWheelSliceProtocol, Codable {
 
    enum Style {
             case blue
             case purple
             case green
             case grey
             case orange
             case yellow
             
         }
         var style: Style = .blue
         var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
                   
               switch style {
               case .blue: return TTUtils.uiColor(from: 0xdff9fb)
               case .purple: return TTUtils.uiColor(from: 0xa29bfe)
               case .green: return TTUtils.uiColor(from: 0x7bed9f)
               case . grey: return TTUtils.uiColor(from: 0xdfe4ea)
               case .orange: return TTUtils.uiColor(from: 0xffbe76)
               case .yellow: return TTUtils.uiColor(from: 0xf6e58d)
                   
               default: print("error getting colors")
               }
           }
  
        var title: String
        var degree: CGFloat = 0.0
        
    
    
    init(title: String) {
      self.title = title
    }
    
      
    
        var fontColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor.black
    }


        var offsetFromExterior: CGFloat {
        return 10.0
        
    }
    
        var stroke: StrokeInfo? {
        return StrokeInfo(color: UIColor.white, width: 1.0)
    }
    
    
    
    
    convenience init(title: String, degree: CGFloat) {
        self.init(title: title)
        self.degree = degree
    }
    

}
```

Comment: enum Style:String will work

Comment: Not related, but you could simplify your code by associating the hex values directly (either as ints or strings): `enum Style: Int, Codable` & `case blue = 0xdff9fb`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every property of a codable class needs to be codable itself if you want it to work automatically (that is, without defining the custom `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)` methods).

The problem is `var style: Style`. `Style` is not codable. The easiest way to do this is by making it a string-based enum

```
enum Style: String, Codable
```

If you do that then, for example, your class would be encoded to JSON with a field like this

```
"style": "green"
```